# Rockets with boosters firing before first stage?

Tags: launch-vehicle

Is there any rocket where the first stage is ignited after the boosters? Say at least 30 seconds after the boosters.

Because in general the first stage is ignited in the same time with the boosters.

Similar question

[How often did launch vehicles have a "Stage 0", and what does it mean exactly?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36854/how-often-did-launch-vehicles-have-a-stage-0-and-what-does-it-mean-exactly)

Comment: Only slightly related because they're not first stages: [Where is Farside's 4th stage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36260/12102) and links therein, and also [How common are “parallel stages” in a launch vehicle?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36268/12102)

Comment: In most cases I think that would mean that the boosters are the first stage.

Comment: That's basically a naming question. The Atlas V calls the stage that is ignited on the pad "booster", and that stage does indeed fully burn out before the next stage (called "upper stage") ignites.

Comment: @ikrase a question about "stage zero" https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36854/6944

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Titan IIIE-Centaurs (and some other Titan versions) lifted off on solid rocket motor (SRM) power only and ignited the liquid first stage **shortly before** SRM jettison.

> Titan Stage I ignition occurs at approximately 112 seconds after liftoff. The actual time is controlled by three majority-voted acceleration switches which command ignition and initiate a staging timer when vehicle acceleration reduces to 1.5g. Approximately 12 seconds later the SRMs are jettisoned upon command from the staging timer.

[image]

[TITAN IIIE/CENTAUR D-IT
SYSTEMS SUMMARY](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19750004937.pdf)

See also

- [Need help understanding staging shown in infographic of Titan launch of Hexagon satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36853/6944)
- [Why do some rockets not ignite all their engines during liftoff? (GSLV MK3 LV)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18178/6944) (this question states that the GSLV MK3 also lifts off on solids with the liquid core not started)

Comment: Is there any term to distinguish such rockets from those that ignite 1st stage at T0?

Comment: Don't know of one.

Comment: maybe this can also be added to answer(s) to the 2nd question in [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48620/rockets-with-boosters-firing-before-first-stage#comment157228_48620)

Comment: @JoeJobs: Some people would understand the term [Asparagus staging](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Asparagus_staging)

Comment: I think asparagus staging it implies fuel cross feed.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the late model Titans that Organic Marble mentions, India's GSLV-III also does this, [as described in this QA](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18178/why-do-some-rockets-not-ignite-all-their-engines-during-liftoff-gslv-mk3-lv?noredirect=1&lq=1).

From a theoretical perspective, if you simply label the boosters as "first stage", and the first stage as "second stage", this is equivalent to ordinary staging.